# Deleting test rows with an auto increment key in a unit test

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing

Is there any ways to delete the rows inserted by a test case in an unit test?

Usually if the key is an auto-increment one I have to store the ID of the rows where the test case inserted so I can delete them during the tearing down phase.

However, sometimes the test case crashes or throws an unexpected error where the tea down phase does not occur (In my case it's PHP's fatal exception error). I am having problem removing those newly created rows in such cases.

I have considered assign a chunk of IDs for testing, say 1 to 100; but as the code inserting the rows is using an auto incrementing key, I cannot force the code to use the IDs reserved for testing.

Is there any way I can 'tag' a row as 'testing' so I may easily clean them up outside of a test case in case it crashes?

I am using PHP, SimpleTest and MySQL

Comment: If you know the values of the test data you are inserting (and its not the same as data that you don't want to delete) you could just do `delete from <tblname> where <column>=<test_value>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice is to use a special blank database just for tests. Then in `setUp()` you fill your tables with test data, and in `tearDown()` you clean everything.

To be more precise: declare some `cleanDatabase()` method and invoke it in 2 places, in setup and in teardown.

Comment: My question did state I do follow the standard practice. It's when the test case crashes and tearDown() doesn't run, and I couldn't store the ID of the newly inserted row. If I do use a test database, it means I cannot run the unit tests on a live application for validation and troubleshooting.

Comment: @Extrakun: the standart practice is when **unit tests** are working with blank test database.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misconception. I did a bit of reading to verify what you said and it seems that you are right. However, I can't up-vote your answer till you edit it. I'll just accept it as it is.